# How to deal with Compiler-Generated code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, disassembly

I'm trying to edit an assembly with Visual Studio, however i disassemble it and open as  VS project, i get unexpectedly large amount of errors, analyzing these i figured most of the errors are caused by "missing fields" in the classes, it appears everything which should be generated by the Compiler is "missing" the following sample should express better what i'm trying to say

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Dictionary<string, int> <>f__switch$mapA;
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Dictionary<string, int> <>f__switch$mapB;
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Dictionary<string, int> <>f__switch$mapC;
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Dictionary<string, int> <>f__switch$mapD;
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Dictionary<string, int> <>f__switch$mapE;
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Dictionary<string, int> <>f__switch$mapF;
private ApplyTween apply;
private AudioSource audioSource;
private static GameObject cameraFade;
private Color[,] colors;
public float delay;
```

The ones which doesn't have the tag "[CompilerGenerated]" appear in the solution browser as identical structures, however the ones that have this tag doesn't and these lines have cause most of the errors. Is it happening cause the disassembling went wrong or something else is to blame? Any help is appreciated (however I'm dealing with over 4000 errors so it'd be difficult to correct them manually one by one).

Comment: what's your decompiler?

Comment: I tried lots of decompilers, but none worked, dotPeek, .NET reflector plugins (file disassembler or file generator)

Comment: The days that decompilers can recover source code are over and done with.  The C# compiler is an excellent obfuscator.

Comment: @Hans can you clarify that? I crack open .net assemblies all the time in JustDecomile...

Comment: So you are saying probably the decompiling/disassembling went wrong?